# Applying filters to data of the form {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, signal-processing

When working with any kind of measurement data there is (at least) for me always a phase where I have to play around with different filters (such as `MedianFilter`, `MeanFilter`, `LowpassFilter` ...) to figure out how to improve my data in some aspect (filtering noise, detecting outliers, detecting edges...). Two things have always bugged me when using the build-in filter functions:

1. filters expect simple list like `{y1,y2,y3,y4}` when (more often than not) measurement data is of the form `{{x1,y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}}` where $x_i$ is some index (e.g. time or frequency) and $y_i$ is the respective measurement (e.g. voltage or force)
2. filters have a syntax of the form `someFilter[data, parameters]` and not an operator form `someFilter[parameters][data]`

This leads often to a [Kuddelmuddel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kuddelmuddel) of `[[]]` mixed with a bunch of `Transpose` and/or intermediate (global) variables

What is a stylistically good way to deal with this?

Comment: Recommend that you include a sample data set and a specific example of how you are filtering it now. It is easier to offer alternate methods if there is a specific example with which to compare.

Comment: Is a "kuddelmuddel" similar to a "muddle puddle tweetle poodle beetle noodle 
bottle paddle battle"?

Comment: @BobHanlon I included an example in my own answer

Comment: @JasonB probably more like "schamozzle" or  "hodge podge"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer I came up with is

```
Clear@applyFilter;
applyFilter[filter_] := Function[data, 
Module[{freq, value},
{freq, value} = Transpose@data;
Transpose[{freq, filter@value}]
]
];

applyFilter[filters__] := RightComposition @@ (applyFilter /@ {filters})

applyFilter[{filter_, n_}] := Nest[applyFilter[filter], # , n] &
```

The features are:

1. Applying filters in operator form

   ```
   applyFilter[MedianFilter[#, 5] &] @ someData
   ```
2. Chaining filters together

   ```
   myfilter = applyFilter[
   MedianFilter[#, 5] &,
   MeanFilter[#,2 ] &
   ]  
   (*used with myfilter @ someData *)
   ```
3. Multiple filter passes

   ```
   applyFilter[{MeanFilter[#, 2] &, numberOfPasses}]
   ```

and can be used on some example data

```
example = Transpose[{Range@100, Accumulate@(RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100])}]
```

[image: example data]

with for instance a `MedianFilter` to flatten the peaks/remove outliers

```
applyFilter[MedianFilter[#, 3] &] @ example
```

[image: median filter]

or a `MedianFilter` followed up by a `MeanFilter` (this can be advantageous compared to using only a `MeanFilter` if there are huge outliers in the data)

```
applyFilter[MedianFilter[#, 3] &, MeanFilter[#, 2] &] @ example
```

[image: median filter + mean filter]

or multiple passes of some filter (1 pass through `MedianFilter` and 10 passes through `MeanFilter`)

```
applyFilter[MedianFilter[#, 3] &, {MeanFilter[#, 2] &, 10}] @ example
```

[image: median + 10 passes mean]

For me at least, something like `applyFilter` makes using the build-in filters a lot more user-friendy when experimenting with data.

```
Manipulate[
ListLinePlot[{
example,
applyFilter[MedianFilter[#, r] &, {MeanFilter[#, r1] &, n}]@example}],

{{r, 0, "Medianfilter radius"}, 0, 10, 1}, Delimiter,
{{n, 0, "Meanfilter passes"}, 0, 10, 1},
{{r1, 0, "Meanfilter radius"}, 0, 10, 1}]
```

[image: gif]

Comment: you can use `MapAt` in your `applyFilter` to save from copying the data to temporary variables.   `applyFilter[filter_] := 
 Function[data, Transpose@MapAt[filter, Transpose@data, {2}]]`

Comment: @george2079 Thanks for your suggestion! If you want I can add it to my answer.