# How to get a smooth derivative graphic

Tags: data, filtering, signal-processing

You can get `data` by this code:

```
data = Normal[Databin["fHVr7FSi"]]
```

Visualize it like following

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can find some non derivable points.So when I show its derivative graphic,it will be:

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[Interpolation[data, x], x]], {x, 
  Sequence @@ MinMax[First /@ data]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I want get this style graphic:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I smooth the primitive `data` by `MeanFilter`

```
f = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{First /@ data, MeanFilter[Last /@ data, 200]}], x];
Plot[f, {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[First /@ data]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the derivative graphic is ugly still

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[f, x]], {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[First /@ data]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Probably the derivative based on data is actually that noisy and you have to use some judgment about how to smooth the data.  The approach [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115444/mathematica-interpolation-or-approximation/115621#115621) approximates the curve with (Chebyshev series) polynomial of an appropriately chosen degree.

Comment: Does the solution in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/90130/1871) help? BTW, does the URL `"http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"` still work?

Comment: I think there are some difference with your link?And that link [work fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/roAT2.png) still.Or you can get it by this code `data = Normal[Databin["fHVr7FSi"]]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm sorry for fail to understand that post.

Comment: since i have some idea what that data represents, I'd suggest your measurement error is likely primarily in the x- data.  Try applying `MedianFilter` to the x instead of y.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think one issue is that your initial data is not evenly sampled and thus filtering it directly is not going to do much good in regards to differentiating it.

I propose resampling of the data, filtering, differentiating and possibly filtering the resulting derivative again. For convenience I will use a custom function [`applyFilter`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126262/applying-filters-to-data-of-the-form-x1-y1-x2-y2/126265#126265) that is again reproduced at the end of this answer.

To resample the data I use `Interpolation` and `Table`

```
interpolation = Interpolation[data];
(resampledData = Table[{x, interpolation@x}, {x, 0, 0.2, 0.0001}] // 
applyFilter[MedianFilter[#, 30] &, MeanFilter[#, 10] &]) // ListPlot
```

together with `applyFilter` to apply first a `MedianFilter` to remove outliers and `MeanFilter` to smooth the result. (You have to play around with the radius parameters for those filters depending on how fine you want to resample)

For differentiating the data `Interpolation` is used again

```
interpolationDiff = Interpolation[resampledData]'; (* note the ' *)
```

which can be sampled

```
diffdata = Table[{x, interpolationDiff@x}, {x, 0, 0.2, 0.0001}]
```

and filtered again via

```
diffdata //applyFilter[MedianFilter[#, 10] &, MeanFilter[#, 10] &]
```

[image: result]

Instead of my chosen combination of `MedianFilter` and `MeanFilter` you can of course use any other linear/nonlinear filters, which might yield better results.

---

**Definition for `applyFilter`**

```
Clear@applyFilter;
applyFilter[filter_] := Function[data, 
Module[{freq, value},
{freq, value} = Transpose@data;
Transpose[{freq, filter@value}]
]
];

applyFilter[filters__] := RightComposition @@ (applyFilter /@ {filters})

applyFilter[{filter_, n_}] := Nest[applyFilter[filter], # , n] &
```

Comment: I benefit a lot from your answer.Thanks. :)

Comment: @yode you are welcome:)

Answer (score 6):

I see you're smoothing the data, but why not smooth the derivative instead?

```
(*Take a list of forward differences between points*)
ddata = Differences[Last /@ data];

(*Divide the differences by the difference in `x' value*)
ddata = ddata/Differences[First /@ data];

(*Apply a MeanFilter to the list of forward differences. 
This will be plotted alongside ddata.*)
ddataFiltered = MeanFilter[ddata, 100];

(*Add back in the `x' values so that the data lists are of the form \
{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...} *)
{ddata, ddataFiltered} = 
  Transpose[{Most[First /@ data], #}] & /@ {ddata, ddataFiltered};

(*Plot it!*)
ListLinePlot[{ddata, ddataFiltered}, PlotStyle -> {Thin,Thick},
 PlotLegends -> {"Unfiltered",
   "Filtered Derivative Data"}, PlotLabel -> "Derivative"]
```

[image]

Applying a `MeanFilter` to the forward difference may be a bit crude, but the principle is there.

Comment: Could you add a comparison of filtered and unfiltered data as well?

Comment: @Sascha - Do you mean a `MeanFilter` on `data` with no filter on `ddata`?

Comment: Just the unfiltered version of ddata for comparison before and after smoothing

Comment: @Sascha - Okay, I've done that. I appreciate the suggestion.